# How do I make a video background on Pencil2D transparent?

Tags: animation

I'm using the [Pencil2D application](https://www.pencil2d.org/). How do I make my animation have no background? It has the settings but I can't seem to use them; when I go to File and Export as Movie it shows "Exporter Settings"; it shows transparency but I can't click it and I don't know why. I just want to have a transparent background and add a video to my background for a video animation I'm making.

Comment: What video format are you exporting as?

Comment: You need to slow down, take a breath, and help us help you. What software are you using?

Comment: The program is Pencil 2D. I would guess you have to change the video format to something that supports the Alpha channel like MOV.